# Parallel requests with ajaxSetup dataFilter

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, async-await, promise

I have to hook into an existing ajax-request (that i can not change, it's inside our CMS) and add some extra data. To be more specific it is a media-library loading image-data (json), and I'm adding some more images from an external source.

```js
var promise_waiting = [];

jQuery.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function() {

        // starting external library request, so they can run in parallel
        promise_waiting = new Promise( function(resolve, reject) {
            jQuery.get(external_library_url, {}, function(data) {
                if(data) {
                    console.log('external library request done');
                    resolve(data);
                }
            });
        });

        return true;
    },
    dataFilter: async function (data) {
        console.log('original request done');

        // waiting for that external library request to resolve
        ext_data = await promise_waiting;

        console.log('both requests done');
        return data.concat(ext_data);
    }
})
```

Both requests finish the way i want them to, so that works alright. The problem is that `dataFilter` cannot be an async function, there is no errors or warnings but the code that would be executed after the request (rendering the image-previews) never triggers.

My current only alternative is using a non-async ajax request in `dataFilter`, which is not optimal as both requests individually take a pretty long time.

I'm looking for alternatives to this setup, thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

With no way to change the `$.ajax()` calls and with `beforeSend` & `dataFilter` not allowing for async, you'll need to perform your asynchronous `beforeSend` manually, and I don't think you can avoid having to "hijack" `jQuery.fn.ajax`.

Something like this maybe:-

```
function myBeforeSend(data) {
    return $.get(external_library_url, {})
    .then(ext_data => data.concat(ext_data || []));
}

(function($, beforeSend) { // i.i.f.e.
    // make an alias for $.fn.ajax
    let $.fn.originalAjax = $.fn.ajax;

    // now hijack $.fn.ajax (in a good way)
    $.fn.ajax = function(...args) {
        // allow for $.ajax's flexible args .... $.ajax(url, [settings]) or $.ajax([settings])
        let settings = Object.assign({}, args[1] || {});
        if (typeof args[0] === "string") {
            settings.url = args[0]; // standardise settings to include url.
        }
        return beforeSend(settings.data || [])
        .then(filteredData => $.originalAjax(Object.assign(settings, { 'data':filteredData })));
    };
})(jQuery, myBeforeSend);
```

There's quite a bit of safety around the composition of the `args` but please be sure to test thoroughly.

Comment: I see what you are trying to do here, but i need the result of the original ajax request to merge with my ext_data. Also hijacking ajax did break some other stuff, sadly

Comment: @devssc, "need the result of the original ajax request to merge with my ext_data" ... barring a mistake on my part, that's exactly the way it *should* behave. `beforeSend()` makes the initial request and returns a Promise that delivers the merged data, which is passed in turn to the second ajax request.

Comment: Whoops, one tiny error, `args[2]` should be `args[1]` (edited).

Comment: The issue with other stuff breaking may be due to the `settings.data || []` expression, which defaults to empty array. Maybe defaulting to empty plain object `{}` would be better though that would require `beforeSend()` to differentiate between array and plain object.